# how compare Double.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java

I want to check if a double has `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Is this the right way (version 1):

```
boolean hasMaxVal(double val){
    return val == Double.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

or do i need to do something like this (version 2):

```
boolean hasMaxVal(double val){
    return Math.abs(val - Double.MAX_VALUE) < 0.00001
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with version 1?

Comment: do you want to check if it's equal or almost equal to MAX_VALUE?

Comment: Those two examples actually have the same behaviour, because there is no other double value within `0.00001` of `Double.MAX_VALUE`. Floating point values are approximations, and the larger the scale of the value, the bigger the difference between possible values.

Comment: I dont know if `Double.Max_Value` differs on different machines..I want a bullet proof method to compare for its (near) equality or..

Comment: Well, `double` has fixed size, so `MAX_VALUE` should be the same on every machine, since it will consists of exact same amount of bits and every bit will be set the same.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn good to know. I thought I would have **rounding issues** because nomally comparing double like `d1 ==  d2` is not a good idea..but you say it is safe to do it with `Double.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: @nimo23 It depends what the purpose is of the comparison. There is not a single answer that is correct for all use cases.

Comment: @khelwood I need a correct solution to check if a double is set to `Double.Max_Value`, nothing else. And there must be a single correct answer for that problem.

Comment: I suggest you just use `==` unless you have an actual situation where you know you want to consider other big numbers to be equivalent to it. The difference between `Double.MAX_VALUE` and the next biggest value is huge.

Comment: @khelwood you say "and the next biggest value is huge."..which next value you mean? Is there a next value after MAX_VALUE?:)

Comment: @nimo23 I didn't mean that, but there is double value greater than `Double.MAX_VALUE`. It's `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. You didn't mention that, so I don't know if you want to consider it or not.

Comment: In fact the difference between `Double.MAX_VALUE` and the highest double below it is about 1E292. Whether you consider that difference neglible is up to you.

Comment: Sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java's `double` type is a [double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating-point number. This means there are 53 bits of precision in the mantissa, and hence the precision of the number is limited to about 16 significant figures in a decimal format.

`Double.MAX_VALUE` is approximately 1.798×10<sup>308</sup>, so the 16th significant figure has a magnitude on the order of 10<sup>308 - 16</sup> = 10<sup>292</sup>. We can confirm this using the `Math.ulp` method, which returns a `double` value's "unit of least precision":

```java
> Double.MAX_VALUE
1.7976931348623157E308
> Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE)
1.9958403095347198E292
```

This means if you do want to test for a value "close to" `Double.MAX_VALUE`, it only makes sense to do so within an epsilon of at least `2E292`. Your epsilon of `0.00001` is far too small for there to be any values within that range other than `Double.MAX_VALUE` itself, so your test is equivalent to `val == Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with "so your test is equivalent to version 1". You mean, version 1 is equivalent to version 2? Does this mean that **version 1** is wrong? Do I need to do this instead: `return Math.abs(val - Double.MAX_VALUE) < 2E292`? Using `System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE == Double.MAX_VALUE);` will always print `true`. Which version should I use?

Comment: @nimo23 he means that the epsilon of `0.00001` is way too small because `MAX_VALUE - 0.00001` will result in `MAX_VALUE` due to precision errors and thus it's computationally equivalent to `== MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Whether or not it's wrong depends on what you are trying to achieve. If it is wrong, then what you should do instead also depends on what you are trying to achieve. If `Double.MAX_VALUE - 2E292` is too far from `Double.MAX_VALUE` for your purposes then you should leave the condition as it is. Otherwise you should increase the epsilon, or consider using a different format instead of `double` if you need greater precision for such large numbers.

Comment: ok, to sum up: If I want to test if the value is "close to" I need to do it with an epsilon of at least `2E292`. But if I want to test for **equalitiy** then **version 1** (`Double.MAX_VALUE == Double.MAX_VALUE)` is right way.

Comment: Whether or not it's wrong depends on what you are trying to achieve: I need a correct solution to check if a double is set to `Double.Max_Value`, nothing else. This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: For whatever problem you are solving, how close "close to" means, depends on that problem.

Comment: *I need a correct solution to check if a double is set to Double.Max_Value, nothing else* Then I am confused... why would you even consider testing for a range of values? The way to test for a specific value and nothing else is to use `==`, of course.

Comment: @kaya3 I was teached that double comparisions with pure `=` could lead to wrong results because of **rounding issues**. That's why we must do something like `Double.doubleToLongBits(a) == Double.doubleToLongBits(b)` or using epsilon comparisons. But it seems that this is not almost correct what I thought:)

Comment: `Double.doubleToLongBits(a) == Double.doubleToLongBits(b)` does exactly the same thing as `a == b` except for NaN values. The reason you are taught to avoid `==` on floating-point numbers is because the results of arithmetic may not be exact. It is perfectly appropriate to use `==` on floating-point numbers when their values aren't the result of arithmetic (e.g. if you write `double d = Double.MAX_VALUE;` at the start of a loop, and then you want to check after the loop to see if it's still `Double.MAX_VALUE`), or more rarely in other situations.